# python: passing variable name to a class

Tags: python

I have a python class defined in a module1.py file:

```
class MBVar():
    def __init__(self, var_type, expression):
            self.var_type = var_type
            self.expression = expression
            ... ecc ...
```

I would like to be able to write in a main *.py file:

```
from module1 import MBVar
X = MBVar('integer', 6)
```

and add to my MBVar class:

```
self.name = ???
```

in such a way that: self.name = 'X'.
Is it possible to do this??

Thanks

Comment: You might want to look at the SymPy library since that's what it appears you are trying to recreate

Comment: Not really. A python object doesn't generally know what name you've bound it to unless you tell it. Consider what would happen if you did `X = MBVar('integer', 6); Y = X; Z = Y`? What would you expect the `.name` attribute of `X`, `Y` and `Z` to contain?

Comment: Do you mean that you want  to initialize`self.name` as a new parameter inside __init__, but dont want to send a value when instantiating an object of the class? If yes, thats possible.

Comment: You mean something similar to the behaviour of creating a custom `namedtuple` data type?

Comment: I'm trying to set a parameter, self.name, inside my class in such a way that, when I instantiate the class, X=MBVar('integer', 6), it takes the name of the variable used for the instantiation: self.name = 'X'. If I do Y = MBVar('integer', 6), obviously it should become: self.name = 'Y'

Comment: Why do you want to do that? I don't think that what you want is possible but i think that there is an other way to do what you want to do, at the end

Comment: @mattia: I get that. But `MBVar` has no way of knowing the name that you bind the instance to, unless you explicitly tell it. And as I mentioned earlier, what should the `.name` become if you bind the instance to multiple names?

Comment: Here's another scenario:  `print([MBVar('integer', i) for i in range(5)])`. That creates 5 `MBVar` instances, and none of them are actually bound to a name. So what would you want your magical naming operation to do in that situation?

Comment: You may find this article helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Answer (score 1):

So I Assume you want to pass variable name and value as parameter and assign it to an object, to do that we don't need the type of the variable since python uses duck typing we just have to add the string representation of the variable name in the inbuilt dictionary `__dict__`  as key and the integer as value.

```
class MBVar():
    def __init__(self, var_name, expression):
        self.__dict__[var_name] = expression

    def add_later(self, var_name, expression):
        self.__dict__[var_name] = expression

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name


X = MBVar('name', 6)
print X.get_name() # prints 6
X.add_later('secint',4);
print X.secint #prints 4
X.__dict__['thirdint'] = 7
print X.thirdint #prints 7
```

Comment: This answer doesn't not appear to address the OP's question.

Comment: @PM2Ring It seems the OP isn't clear about the question so that I carefully started with an assumption. will be glad to remove it if my assumption is wrong. I would have added a comment instead but adding this entire thing in comment will be an overkill i thought

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution but i don't think that this is a very good coding practice. Moreover, it is a 2 steps process: it can't be done inside the `__init__` method because till the end of this method, the object has not been yet associated to a variable.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
      self.__name = ""

    def set_name(self, name):
      self.__name = name

    def get_name(self):
      return self.__name

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = Foo()
    b = Foo()
    c = Foo()

    dict_v = locals()

    v = "" 
    # this line initialize the variable of name "v" because of its entry in the locals() dict 
    #-> prevent "RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration "

    for v in dict_v.keys():
      if isinstance(dict_v[v], Foo):
        # the process only happens for the objects of a specific class
        dict_v[v].set_name(v)

    #proof
    print(a.get_name())
    print(b.get_name())
    print(c.get_name())
```